# using an alias inside a window function in Big Query does not work, any way to go around this?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Hi I have some code inside a query in Big Query

```
SELECT anonymous_id, SUM(CAST(plan_cost as decimal)) as plan_cost, CAST(sent_at AS DATE) as date,
COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY anonymous_id, date) as occurrences
FROM `****-348311.****_prod.purchase`
group by anonymous_id, date
order by date asc;
```

sadly the column sent_at is a timestamp so I have to turn it into a date to be able to group by it, but I get an error on the `date` inside `(PARTITION BY anonymous_id, date)`, it says `unrecognised name:date`

Any help in how to fix this  using bigquery?

Comment: use `OVER (PARTITION BY anonymous_id, DATE(sent_at))` . but in reality you don't really need window function here - so you can remove OVER(...) whatsoever and leave just COUNT(*).

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant thanks alot it worked by removing the window function, if you want to post your comment as an answer ill accept as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented by @Mikhail Berlyant, you can use `OVER (PARTITION BY anonymous_id, DATE(sent_at))`. You can also remove the window function OVER(...) and leave just COUNT(*).

Posting the answer as community wiki for the benefit of the community that might encounter this use case in the future.

Feel free to edit this answer for additional information.